# Issues compiling with pdflatex - font errors that appear to reject characters I'm not using?

Tags: fonts, latex, pdflatex

thanks for taking a look.

Long story short, getting a major error when trying to compile a latex file into a pdf. When I try, pdflatex returns this on the terminal:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./report.aux)        (./report.toc)
[1{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6])
*
```

At `*` it asks for an input command, or \end. Upon ending, errors are printed to report.log:

```
[1

{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4] [5]
Missing character: There is no Â in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ­ in font cmr10!

[6])
```

The essay segment in section [5] does not contain Â, and when it's cut out the two character errors leave, but the:

```
[1

{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6])
```

remains

I'd like to point out I'm **not allowed to use packages** in my solution, thanks to submission rules. 
Any suggestions, friends? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My bad! Overall solution seemed to be adding an end{document} tag, which in my haste to submit I had forgot. Thanks for taking a peek anyway, I hope next time my contribution to this forum will be more worthwhile~

Comment: If you can rephrase this as a  real answer, you can mark it as the correct answer tomorrow. If you don't think anyone will benefit from being to find your question + answer in the future, then it's better to delete your question.